# Alternative to rescheduleJob for StdScheduler in Quartz 2.1?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am migrating my project from `Quartz 1.8.x to Quartz 2.1.`

```
List<CronTriggerImpl> cronTriggerList;
private StdScheduler scheduler;
///
/// Other Code

for (CronTriggerImpl cronTrigger : cronTriggerList) {
  if (null == scheduler.rescheduleJob(cronTrigger.getName(),cronTrigger.getGroup(), cronTrigger)) {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(cronTrigger);
     }
  }
```

But this code is giving me error as StdScheduler  does not have `rescheduleJob()` function.

In Quartz 2.1  , `rescheduleJob(TriggerKey, Trigger)` takes 2 arguments.

How i can do this in Quartz 2.1 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extensive guide for migration to 2.X

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide

Constructing a `TriggerKey` from `cronTrigger.getName(),cronTrigger.getGroup()` is trivial using `TriggerKeyBuilder`. Same can be achieved with `Trigger`, the second parameter of `rescheduleJob(TriggerKey, Trigger)` with an equivalent [TriggerBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html). Extract a set of relevant values from your old `CronTriggerImpl cronTrigger` and transform it to a `Trigger` before rescheduling.

Comment: Thanks First Argument is solved. Is it ok if i pass cronTrigger in 2nd argument as Trigger ?